# Numerical solution of ordinary differential equation $y'=-25y$

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I've been given this problem: for differential equation 
\begin{align}
y'=-25y
\end{align}
consider these two Runge-Kutta methods: a) midpoint b) Heun's
Choose whichever is more absolute stable, determine maximal step so that method wouldnt oscilate due to being unstable.

Now from course of calculus I know how to precisely solve this having a general solution of $y(x)=\exp(-25x+c)$ /or for convenience define $d:=\exp(c)$ then $y(x)=d*\exp(-25x)$ / or particular given a initial entry/condition (something like $y(0)=1$). However I do not understand how am I to proceed in this particular case as I'm unable to continue without initial condition. I know the matrices for both of these methods but am unable to continue due to lack of comprehension.

Comment: The only piece of information you're missing is exactly the initial condition, but I guess the point of the problem is to see how different methods perform in this case. I wouldn't worry too much about $y(0)$, just pick something arbitrary, e.g. $y(0) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to the [explicit midpoint method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method).
Since both the midpoint as well as Heun's method are second order accurate methods with two stages, the stability polynomial is
$$P_2(z) = 1 + z +\frac12 z^2.$$

For $z = h(-25 + 0i)$ we need to ensure A-stability, i.e.,

$$\vert P_2(-25 h) \vert \overset{!}{\leq} 1$$
which implies
\begin{align}
1&\overset{!}{\geq} \left \vert 1 - 25 h + \frac12 (-25 h)^2 \right \vert  \\
\Leftrightarrow  1 &\overset{!}{\geq} \left \vert 1 - 25 h + \frac{625}{2} h^2 \right \vert
\end{align}
We note that $Q(h) := 1 - 25 h + \frac{625}{2} h^2$ is a even degree polynomial with positive highes coefficient. As a consequence, we have $\lim_{h \to \pm \infty} Q(h) = \infty $.
We now determine the roots of $Q(h)$ and obtain $x_{1,2} = \frac{1}{25} (1 \pm i)$, thus $Q(h)$ is positive for all real $h$ and we can drop the absolute value:
$$1 \overset{!}{\geq} 1 - 25 h + \frac{625}{2} h^2 $$
We are interested in the maximum stable timestep $h$, thus we solve
\begin{align}
1 &\overset{!}{=} 1 - 25 h + \frac{625}{2} h^2 
\Leftrightarrow 0 &\overset{!}{=} 25h \left(-1 + \frac{25}{2} h \right)
\end{align}
which gives $h = 0$ and $h = \frac{2}{25}$.
Thus, the maximum possible time step is $h = \frac{2}{25}$.